# How to handle iOS update alert with Appium

Tags: java, iphone, appium, ios-ui-automation, appium-ios

I am using Selenium with Appium and my tests run on Android and iOS real device. A set of tests run on android while iOS is idle. Then the test switch to iOS. Both devices are connected at the same time.

Below is the sequence of the suites I'm running using testNG :

```
<suite-file path="android_Suite1.xml" />
<suite-file path="ios_Suite1.xml" />
<suite-file path="android_Suite2.xml" />
<suite-file path="ios_Suite2.xml" />
<suite-file path="android_Suite3.xml" />
<suite-file path="ios_Suite3.xml" />
```

The problem here is iOS device shows os update installation pop-up when the test switch to android. I want to disable the pop-up before the test switch back to iOS. I can delete the update from settings>storage. But the tests run overnight and there is a possibility of the update being downloaded again.
Since this is a system alert, the test wont start because no session is created as appium do not find the homescreen. So the capabilities also wont work.
Need help to handle this specific pop-up.

Comment: pop-up has elements , you can click 'ok'/'cancel element. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: Yes, but the software upgrade pop-up does not have ok/Cancel. it has Install/Later/.. Also, cannot access this pop-up unless iOSdriver is created.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I can give you an exact solution but you could make a two threaded system, one for Android and one for iOS. Then just yield each thread while the other is testing. You will need to be running two instances of Appium to do this (different ports).

Then depending on the exact functionality solve with one of the ways below:

1) Then also have a driver for each running. At that point you could just put into your logic on the iOS side to always dismiss/accept alerts.

2) You could have a thread stem off of the iOS thread that checks for the software popup ever 'x' seconds, then if found dismiss it.

I had a similar issue with asynchronous popups on android which I used option (2) to solve. Your issue seems to be a little bit more problematic than what I had to deal with. Hopefully this can get you started with a good solution though! Sorry for the ambiguous answer.

Comment: Thank you @JaysonP. I will try this approach and update in comments :)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to delete the downloaded update if it is downloaded already then you have to turn off the auto updates as below.

Automatic Updates are enabled by default, so you'll need to turn them off. This won't help with the current update, but it will stop you from getting these messages in future. So the first thing you should do is dive into settings and turn Automatic Updates off:

1. Tap Settings.
2. Tap iTunes & App Stores.
3. Set Updates under "Automatic Downloads" to Off.

This will prevent iOS from downloading updates in future, although you'll still need to deal with the update you've downloaded.